# javascript image cropping/resizing

Tags: javascript, css, image

Right,not sure what this is technically called or how to do this.

But how would you go about getting large images - landscape and portrait, and resizing them so that they fit the dimensions of a particular div without actually losing aspect ratio?

Comment: Do it with `background-image` in CSS.

Comment: but would it stretch if I set the background image as a image?

Comment: It wouldn't stretch if you set it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this CSS entry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) to make the image scale and at the same time cover the entire element. Just note that you need to set the image as background image:

```
background-image:url(...);
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Cool, is there a pure javascript way of doing this?

Comment: @bobo2000 you can use `element.style.backgroundSize = 'cover'` assuming you have obtained  valid element reference.